# C++, error C2448 - function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

This program is supposed to get two inputs from a user and show the answer.
These are the errors i get:

> (15): error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
>
> (15): error C2065: 'y' : undeclared identifier
>
> (16): error C2448: 'writeanswer' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
>
> (30): error C3861: 'writeanswer': identifier not found

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Readnumber()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    return num;
}

    void writeanswer(x, y) //THIS IS LINE 15
{ //THIS IS LINE 16
    int a;
    a = x + y;
    cout << "This is the answer: " << a;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    int x = Readnumber();

    cout << "Please enter another number: ";
    int y = Readnumber();

    writeanswer(x, y); //THIS IS LINE 30


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I think that the error on line 30 is the main problem that is leading to more errors. I have tried Google and I can't seem to fix it.

Edit: I thought I had tried that, I had spent all day on this problem! Thanks to all the answers.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is strongly statically typed, not dynamically typed. You have to write the type of your parameters `x` and `y`.

Exactly as you specified the type of the local variable `a` inside the body of the function, you have to specify the types of the input parameters `x`and `y`:

```
void writeanswer( int x , int y )
```

Comment: Could you give me an example? I am new to C++ so I don't understand this.

Answer (score 5):

In the function declaration for `writeanswer`, you have

```
void writeanswer(x, y)
```

but it should be

```
void writeanswer(int x, int y)
```

The compiler does not know what type x and y are in your code.  It can't imply the data type from your main function, as their scope is limited to the main function in which they were declared.

In some languages, including MATLAB and Python, you do not need to always specify data type as it is implicitly sorted out upon compilation / interpretation based on what type of value you are trying to set it to.  C++ does not work like that.  C++ is very strict in this regard and you must specify every single data type upon declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Line 15 is wrong. You should write it the following way:

```
void writeanswer(int x, int y)
```